Is there a bundler that can be used with normal EOA without AA?
I've been playing around with ERC-4337: Account Abstraction Using Alt Mempool, it seems that there is a way to send multiple transactions and ensures they all returns success in sequential order. However using ERC-4337 requires an entrypoint and factory and the account execution is on a contract.
I was wondering if there is a way to make use of a bundle, ensure the transactions are success in sequential order etc. using a normal EOA. A use case would be able to approve and swap in a single call without a need for a contract, but the execution is on the node level, which I assume the bundler would do. Thanks!

Unfortunately this is not currently possible with EOAs, however EIP-3074 promises to allow for exactly this use case.
Until then ERC-4337 accounts might be the best bet to achieve this.
